# Crear librerías en SAS

Tags: sas

Estoy intentando crear una libería en SAS llamada tabsas.
Para ello primero accedo a archivo, nuevo, programa y allí creo una carpeta llamada tabsas, después escribo lo siguiente:

```
       libname tabsas '/home/usuarioID/tabsas';
```

Se supone que me debería aparecer dentro de los mensajes de log el mensaje de:

```
       NOTE: libref successfully assigned as follow: Engine: V9 Physical Name: /home/usuarioID/tabsas
```

Pero no me sale. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que es correcto.
Yo probaría a poner comillas dobles.
Otro problema es la ruta, es la ruta absoluta o relativa, esa ruta está mapeada?
Si estas en sas base puedes crear la librería por el asistente sin Código, botón derecho en librería y crear una nueva, prueba de esa forma.
Por otro lado si es sas guide posiblemente no puedas acceder a tu local ya que está en servidor.
Prueba y sino me comentas!
Un saludo